# Pytorch RNN HTML Generation

Tags: python, html, nlp, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I’ m stuck for a couple of days trying to make and **RNN network** to **learn** a **basic HTML template**.
I tried different approaches and I even **overfit** on the following data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Obtaining **100% accuracy on training and validation** using **Adam** Optimizer and **CrossEntropyLoss**.

The problem is that when I try to sample from the network, the **results** are completely **random** and I don’t know whats the **problem**:

```
..<a<a<a<a<aa<ttp11111b11111b11111111b11b1bbbb<btttn111
```

My **sampling function** is the following:

```
def sample_sentence():
    words = list()
    count = 0
    modelOne.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Setup initial input state, and input word (we use "the").
        previousWord = torch.LongTensor(1, 1).fill_(trainData.vocabulary['letter2id']['[START]'])
        hidden =  Variable(torch.zeros(6, 1, 100).to(device))


        while True:
            # Predict the next word based on the previous hidden state and previous word.
            inputWord = torch.autograd.Variable(previousWord.to(device))


            predictions, newHidden = modelOne(inputWord, hidden)

            hidden = newHidden


            pred = torch.nn.functional.softmax(predictions.squeeze()).data.cpu().numpy().astype('float64')

            pred = pred/np.sum(pred)


            nextWordId = np.random.multinomial(1, pred, 1).argmax()


            if nextWordId == 0:
                continue

            words.append(trainData.vocabulary['id2letter'][nextWordId])
            # Setup the inputs for the next round.
            previousWord.fill_(nextWordId)


            # Keep adding words until the [END] token is generated.
            if nextWordId == trainData.vocabulary['letter2id']['[END]']:
                break

            if count>20000:
                break
            count += 1
        words.insert(0, '[START]')


        return words
```

And my network architecture is here:

```
class ModelOne(Model) :
    def __init__(self,
                vocabulary_size,
                hidden_size,
                num_layers,
                rnn_dropout,
                embedding_size,
                dropout,
                num_directions):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.vocabulary_size = vocabulary_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.rnn_dropout = rnn_dropout
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.num_directions = num_directions
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size


        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(self.vocabulary_size, self.embedding_size)
        self.rnn = nn.GRU(self.embedding_size,
                          self.hidden_size,
                          num_layers=self.num_layers,
                          bidirectional=True if self.num_directions==2 else False,
                          dropout=self.rnn_dropout,
                          batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size*self.num_directions, self.vocabulary_size)





    def forward(self, paddedSeqs, hidden):

        batchSequenceLength = paddedSeqs.size(1)

        batchSize = paddedSeqs.size(0)

        lengths = paddedSeqs.ne(0).sum(dim=1)

        embeddingVectors = self.embeddings(paddedSeqs)

        x = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embeddingVectors, lengths, batch_first=True)

        self.rnn.flatten_parameters()

        x,hid = self.rnn(x, hidden)

        output, _ = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(x, batch_first=True, padding_value=0, total_length=batchSequenceLength)

        predictions = self.linear(output)


        return predictions.view(batchSize, self.vocabulary_size, batchSequenceLength), hid

    def init_hidden(self, paddedSeqs):
        hidden = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers*self.num_directions,
                                    1,
                                    self.hidden_size).to(device))
        return hidden



modelOne =ModelOne(vocabulary_size=vocabularySize,
                 hidden_size=100,
                 embedding_size=50,
                 num_layers=3,
                 rnn_dropout=0.0,
                 dropout=0,
                 num_directions=2).to(device)
```

If you have any idea of what needs to be changed, please let me know.
I added all the code to github repository here: https://github.com/OverclockRo/HTMLGeneration/blob/SamplingTestTemplate/Untitled.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all for a GRU (RNN) to be efficient, you may need more data to train.

Second, it seems that you have a problem with the embedding. It looks like, the mapping vocabulary['id2letter'] does not work, otherwise you would obtain 
sequences of tags like `<head><title><title><title>`, instead of `p111`.

**EDIT**

I have trained [this character-level GRU network](https://github.com/spro/char-rnn.pytorch) on the html source code of [this page](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) for 1700 epochs. And here an example 2000-character excerpt of what it generates:

```
A+Implexementation--nope bande that shoos</td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="296"></td><td class="line-content">              </td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="1437"></td><td class="line-content">                    <span class="html-tag">&lt;/a&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="755"></td><td class="line-content">                </td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="584"></td><td class="line-content">    <span class="html-tag">&lt;a <span class="html-attribute-name">data-controller</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">footer__menu__link</span>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;div <span class="html-attribute-name">data-target</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">release__line</span>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;a <span class="html-attribute-name">class</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">/hase__version-date</span>"&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="174"></td><td class="line-content"><br></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="1315"></td><td class="line-content">Bule and the use the twith a hoas suiecode excess ardates</td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="1003"></td><td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;/a&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="129"></td><td class="line-content">              </td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="269"></td><td class="line-content">              <span class="html-tag">&lt;/ul&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="591"></td><td class="line-content">                <span class="html-tag">&lt;/div&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="553"></td><td class="line-content">    <span class="html-tag">&lt;div <span class="html-attribute-name">href</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-external-link" target__link</td><td class="line-content">              </td></tr><tr><td class="line-number" value="103"></td><td class="line-content">    </td></tr><tr><td cla
```

I hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response sir. It is a character by character generator, so it should learn how to generate the tags.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't and honestly I don't know what to do from this step forward.

Comment: If it is a character by character generator, than '[Start]' and '[End]' should be escape characters as well, not strings.

Comment: I have also expanded the answer with an example character-level RNN.

Comment: Its true. I encoded [START] and [END] as single int values in tensors and I just display them in this manner. Thanks a lot for the suggested solution sir. Its really helpfull.